# Slowness of an ssh tunnel to use phpmyadmin

Tags: ssh-tunnel, phpmyadmin

I installed phpmyadmin locally (on Linux Mint 19), with which I manage mysql 5.7 databases on a remote VPS (running Ubuntu 18.04), via ssh tunnel.

I create the tunnel with this command:

```
ssh -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 root@example.com -N -v
```

It works, but phpmyadmin is extremely slow. In contrast, the server is very fast and ssh connectivity is also very fast.

I don't know what is causing the problem, I accept suggestions to solve, thank you.

Comment: Could you post TEXT results of A) first page of report from OS command prompt of either HTOP or TOP ? and B) a slow query and C) EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE (your slow query); for a quick look?

Comment: same here, the mysql cli through the same tunnel is very fast, but phpmyadmin is extremely slow

Comment: @nulll See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I did not understand the cause of the problem, I found an acceptable workaround.

Assuming that the command `ssh -L 3307:127.0.1:3306 root@example.com -N -v` is run in Linux Mint 19 inside a VirtualBox guest machine, as I wrote in the question phpMyAdmin works extremely slow. If I run `ssh -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 root@example.com -N -v` from the host machine (Linux Mint 18.3 KDE), and then open phpMyAdmin from the host machine, there is a significant speed increase: phpMyAdmin goes from being extremely slow to having an acceptable slowness.

I'm aware that this is not a generalizable solution, but it is related to my specific case, however I hope it will be useful for other people as well.

However, further consideration, I point out that in the first one the port forwarding is from 3307 to 3306, in the second one it commands from 3306 to 3306 (this second command is not applicable inside the guest machine because the 3306 port is already occupied by the local mysql installation).